# Change the Category Name with ACF inside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following loop:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt-a',
        'category_name' => 'my-category',
        'posts_per_page' => 99,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'paged' => $paged);
            $loop = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($loop->have_posts()) :
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        
                <div><?php echo get_the_content(); ?></div>
                <span ><?php the_title(); ?></span>

<?php endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Is it possible to use a custom field (ACF) instead of "`my-category`"? I tried all the known options, but I could not find a working solution.

Comment: Custom field of what, exactly? A single one, determine by whatever the "parent" page or post is here? Or one stored on each of the individual posts you want this query to return?

Comment: Hello @CBroe, thank you for your response. I am trying to achieve something like

 'category_name' => '<?php echo $section_reviews['reviews_cat']; ?>'

Of course, what I showed does not work and WordPress gives a critical error. So I am here since I cannot figure out how to convert this code,

Comment: The PHP tags of course do not belong there - you _are_ in PHP tags already, and they can't be nested. This should just be `'category_name' => $section_reviews['reviews_cat'],`

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much! Itis working :) You can't even imagine how you helped me!  Please add this solution as a separate answer so I can submit it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to use the value of a variable in the place where there was a static text literal before, but with

```
'category_name' => '<?php echo $section_reviews['reviews_cat']; ?>'
```

you have written invalid code. You are inside PHP tags here already, and those can not be nested.

You simply need to put the variable name there,

```
'category_name' => $section_reviews['reviews_cat'],
```